# Smooth camera transition when mouse re-enters canvas - Three.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I am attempting to move an object with Three.js by having the object track the mouse movements of a user. Whenever the mouse leaves the canvas and re-enters the canvas in a different spot, the object will jump to the position of the mouse in the new spot.

I am trying to avoid this jerky object movement and have it smoothly transition to the new location of the mouse when a user moves their cursor off screen and has it re-enter in a new position.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
var canvas = renderer.domElement;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
box.geometry.translate(0, 0, 0.5);
box.scale.set(1, 1, 3);
scene.add(box);

var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), -10);
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);


//Move object view based on user mouse position
function onMouseMove(event){
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);
  box.lookAt(pointOfIntersection);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  if (resize(renderer)) {
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

function resize(renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
}
```

Example of jump when moving mouse in canvas, then move mouse out of canvas to new position, and finally re-entering canvas: https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/yGMWNg

Comment: The same would apply if you move the mouse really fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to store the box look x y position in addition to the current mouse x y position coordinates.

Then inside the loop call an update function. Inside the update function you will ease the look position towards the current mouse position.

You then use `lookPosition` instead of `mouse` in `raycaster.setFromCamera`.

The easing can look like this:

```
const easeAmount = 8;
function update(){
  lookPosition.x += ( mouse.x - lookPosition.x ) / easeAmount;
  lookPosition.y += ( mouse.y - lookPosition.y ) / easeAmount;
}
```

Working solution:

https://codepen.io/cdigital/pen/aboEeGp

Comment: Awesome. Do you know how to do it when loading a .gltf file? I'm using the GLTFLoader though it causes problems with the ```.lookAt ```call from inside ```update()```